# How to check if the app is running on iOS device or simulator

Tags: ios, delphi, ios-simulator, delphi-xe6

Based on this link [Conditional compilation (Delphi)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Conditional_compilation_%28Delphi%29#Predefined_Conditionals) CPUARM conditional if should be false for Simulator and true for device, the problem is it's not working for me.
I am using `Delphi XE6, iOS Simulator 7.1`

This is my code

```
    {$IFDEF CPUARM}
s := 'iOS device';
    {$ELSE}
s := 'iOS Simulator';
    {$ENDIF}
```

p.s iOS Simulator is running in a VMWare virtual machine.

Comment: You should **always** add the common `delphi` tag to your Delphi related questions. Maybe you were wondering for the low attention on your questions. That is the reason :o)

Comment: @RobKennedy, actually, no. The iOS simulator does not run the same binary that is deployed to iOS devices. The simulator runs x86 compiled code, not ARM compiled code.  So it is not a single compilation. Checking for CPUARM is the correct way to differentiate between an iOS device and an iOS simulator.

Answer (score 9):

Checking for `CPUARM` is the correct solution. iOS binaries compiled for the simulator are not ARM, they are actually x86.  Just make sure to wrap your iOS code with `{$IFDEF IOS}`:

```
{$IFDEF IOS}
  {$IFDEF CPUARM}
s := 'iOS device';
  {$ELSE}
s := 'iOS Simulator';
  {$ENDIF}
{$ENDIF}
```

Delphi uses an ARM compiler for iOS devices, but uses an x86 compiler for the iOS simulator.

The available compiler conditionals are documented on Embarcadero's DocWiki:

[Conditional compilation (Delphi) | Predefined Conditionals](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Conditional_compilation_(Delphi)#Predefined_Conditionals)

`CPUARM` is defined by the [DCCIOSARM compiler](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/DCCIOSARM.EXE,_the_Delphi_Compiler_for_the_iOS_Device) (iOS device).

`CPU386` and `CPUX86` are defined by the [DCCIOS32 compiler](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/DCCIOS32.EXE,_the_Delphi_Compiler_for_the_iOS_Simulator) (iOS simulator).

A look at the conditional values that are physically present in XE6's DCCIOSARM.EXE and DCCIOS32.EXE executable files confirms that:

DCCIOSARM.EXE:

```
**CPUARM**
DCC
NEXTGEN
AUTOREFCOUNT
WEAKINSTREF
WEAKINTFREF
WEAKREF
EXTERNALLINKER
NATIVECODE
POSIX
POSIX32
MACOS
MACOS32
**IOS**
VER270
CONSOLE
BCB
PIC
UNICODE
CONDITIONALEXPRESSIONS
```

DCCIOS32.EXE:

```
**CPU386**
**CPUX86**
DCC
NEXTGEN
AUTOREFCOUNT
WEAKINSTREF
WEAKINTFREF
WEAKREF
NATIVECODE
POSIX
POSIX32
MACOS
MACOS32
**IOS**
ALIGN_STACK
UNDERSCOREIMPORTNAME
PC_MAPPED_EXCEPTIONS
ASSEMBLER
VER270
CONSOLE
BCB
PIC
UNICODE
CONDITIONALEXPRESSIONS
```

---

UPDATE: starting with Delphi 11.2, the ARM-based iOS simulator is now supported via the new [DCCIOSSIMARM64](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/DCCIOSSIMARM64) compiler. You can use the `IOSSIMULATOR` conditional to check for that compiler:

```
{$IFDEF IOS}
  {$IFDEF CPUARM}
    {$IFDEF IOSSIMULATOR}
s := 'iOS Simulator (ARM)';
    {$ELSE}
s := 'iOS device';
    {$ENDIF}
  {$ELSE}
s := 'iOS Simulator (x86)';
  {$ENDIF}
{$ENDIF}
```

Comment: I had checked the documentation and I used CPUARM and IOS as you write, but surprisingly it didn't work.

Comment: I assure you, it does. There is no possible way that `CPUARM` can be defined when compiling for the iOS Simulator, unless something else in your project is defining it manually. As you can see in my answer, `CPUARM` does not physically exist in DCCIOS32.

Comment: "*There is no possible way that CPUARM can be defined when compiling for the iOS Simulator*" - that is no longer the case starting in Delphi 11.2, which adds support for the ARM-based simulator via the new [DCCIOSSIMARM64](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/DCCIOSSIMARM64) compiler. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I found a workaround for this problem:

I defined a `ISSIM` condition for `ALL Configuration - IOS Simulator Platform` in Project->Options page , then I checked that via this

```
    {$IFDEF ISSIM}
s := 'iOS Simulator';
    {$ELSE}
s := 'iOS device';
    {$ENDIF}
```

[image]

Comment: It is not necessary to define your own value, the existing compiler conditionals are sufficient.