# Linking C Obj Files in FireMonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I'm evaluating a project to determine whether it is practical to port to FireMonkey.

It links a lot of c obj files. I cannot find any information regarding C obj linking support in FireMonkey. Can anyone advise whether it works?

Thanks

Comment: This is unrelated to FireMonkey. But yes, you can link to object files, as @David says in his answer. For Win32, some more info on this can be found here: [Using C object files in Delphi](http://www.rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cobjs.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not actually related to FireMonkey. Your question is whether or not the Delphi compiler supports linking objects. That is a question at the compiler level rather than the library level.

And the answer is that external objects can be linked for all the various compiler targets: Windows, Mac, iOS, Android and Linux.

You will of course need to recompile each of your external objects for each target that you wish to support.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, David

Comment: except with ios simulator :)

Comment: @loki you are linking objects that target x86?

Comment: the same library as i link to the real device, so i guess no

Comment: @loki Well, the [iOS simulator is x86](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23810897/), so you would need your objects to match.

Comment: aah maybe .. never try